# object of type 'externalptr' is not subsettable in R4.0 - with COM Object

Tags: r

do anyone experience this error
In R4.0

I used the command and got an error

```
ss <- comCreateObject('InternetExplorer.Application')

ss[['Visible']]

Error in ss[["Visible"]] : 
  object of type 'externalptr' is not subsettable
```

While in R3.6, the code is successfully performed.
does R4.0 modify something in subsettable flag?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem, just posting here for audience information. The key problem is R4.0 does not recognize [[ primitive function for ss object; while R3.6 accept.

- Context:

comCreateObject is a function of a library called COMLib.

ss object is a COMClassObject

The [[ function has been declared in COMLib

- Solution: define S3method instruction in COMLib library. Then reinstall COMLib.

In COMLib.r: "[[.COMClassObject" <- function (handle, property, ...)

In NAMESPACE file:        S3method("[[",COMClassObject)